# Future Perfect in Italian

Tags: verbs, translation, tenses

I need to translate this sentence to Italian

> The year 1300 was to see an increased sale in coffee.

I did some research (I am not an expert). The tense seems to be future perfect, and the Italian equivalent would be 'futuro anteriore'. But I still cannot figure out what that would look like, especially the 'was to see'.

My attempt

> L'anno 1300 era da vedere un sostanziale aumento di vendite di caffè.

Comment: The English sentence does not make any sense to me.

Comment: It is a sentence written on the past (1300) and on the immediate future of that point in time.

Comment: You need to convert your sentence to proper English first :)  "was to see" is colloquial; the 'proper' version is "The year 1300 *would see* an increased sale in coffee".  With that, the answer you've got should be perfectly clear :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you add "sostanziale" to your translation? The original sentence is about a generic increase, not a substantial one.

Comment: @Postmortes, indeed but the orginal text is not very well written

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *futuro anteriore* (in a first approximation) denotes an event that is going to happen earlier than another future one (for which the *futuro (semplice)* is used). The *futuro anteriore* is constructed with the future of an auxiliary verb (*essere* or *avere*) and the past participle of the verb we need. For instance:

> Quando tutto *sarà finito*, andremo in vacanza.

(Compare, for instance, with: “Domani finirà tutto. Dopodomani andremo in vacanza”, with two uses of *futuro semplice*.)

But what you need in your example is not this, a “past in the future”, but rather a “future in the past”, and this is expressed in Italian with the *passato* tense of the *condizionale* mood. Hence, a sentence like yours can be expressed as:

> L'anno 1300 *avrebbe visto* un sostanziale aumento nelle vendite del caffè.